# OCaml: dune build error after running `dune init exec`

Tags: ocaml, dune

I am new to OCaml, and I followed the [tutorial](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/up_and_running.html) to set up a developpement environment. I then tried the [helloworld](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/up_and_running.html#A-first-project) example with dune and OCaml but encoutered the following error:

```
$ dune init exe helloworld
Success: initialized executable component named helloworld
$ dune build
Error: I cannot find the root of the current workspace/project.
If you would like to create a new dune project, you can type:

    dune init project NAME

Otherwise, please make sure to run dune inside an existing project or
workspace. For more information about how dune identifies the root of the
current workspace/project, please refer to
https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#finding-the-root
```

Directory structure:

```
.
├── _build
│   └── log
├── dune
└── helloworld.ml
```

dune: 3.0.2
ocaml: 4.11.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fix this situation by adding a `dune-project` file at the root of your project filled with this line:

```
(lang dune 3.0)
```

However, as per the documentation, `dune init exec` is not intended for creating projects: it only creates the boilerplate for an executable component **within an existing project** (see `dune init --help` or the [dune cli manual](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#initializing-components-1) for details).

To initialize a project, you should run

```
dune init proj helloworld
```

This will also generate a template `dune-project` file along with the recommended project file structure.

---

**NOTE:** Prior to dune 3.0 `dune build` would have created the file for you if it was absent:

```
❯ dune init exe helloworld
Success: initialized executable component named helloworld
❯ ls
_build  dune  helloworld.ml
❯ dune build
Info: Creating file dune-project with this contents:
| (lang dune 2.9)
❯ ls
_build  dune  dune-project  helloworld.ml
```

However, since dune 3.0, `dune-project` is not added automatically when not found in the project.

Comment: Solved, I find [Remove support for creating and editing the dune-project file automatically](https://github.com/ocaml/dune/issues/4108)

Comment: I added a few additions to clarify the intended use of `dune init exec` vs. `dune init proj`. Besides the breaking change in dune around `dune build` behavior, this problem is due to an incorrect tutorial. I've submitted a fix for the tutorial here: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml.org/pull/325

Comment: Thanks for the edits. From what I understand, `dune init` has always been a "side-project" but a lot of newcomers use it so it's good if we can finally have a good documentation for it.